# Python - Monotic time giving too little decimals

Tags: python, time

For some functions i have to add a time variable to a queue which is read by another Process.
First i used time.time but as the clock can be rolled backwards etc, i went looking for another option. I found time.monotonic() which can only move forward, however, at most it gives me three decimals. time.monotonic_ns returns the exact same but just in nanoseconds. With time.time i am recieving the time with 6 decimals. I need those 6 decimals but with time.monotonic. Is there a way to make time.monotonic return more decimals then three? If so, how? If not, are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You're on Windows, right?

You might want to read [PEP 418](https://peps.python.org/pep-0418/) which details the implementation of time.monotonic().  It also explains why it uses only 3 decimal places for Windows.

You could probably implement it yourself using `QueryPerformanceCounter()`, but as the documentation says, that has problems.